# Запятая между "то" и "что", если "то" — местоимение

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, орфоэпия

1.1. Если "то" - это местоимение, а "что" - союз или союзное слово, то слова "то" и "что" надо разделить запятой. Почему в данном случае большинство неверно пишет "то, что" без запятой или даже слитно, а говорят "то, что" молниеносно, не замечая запятой; напротив, ставя паузу перед "то"? И обоснований я не знаю.

1.2. Можете высказать свои мысли насчёт данной ошибки, можете к истории обратиться. Отвечайте так, как вам угодно.

Comment: «... большинство неверно пишет "то, что" без запятой.» Примеры имеются? Приведите их.

Comment: "Почему неграмотно пишут?" - вопрос слишком общий.

Comment: М_Г, я сказал "большинство".

Comment: shampar, "<…>и ты обижаешься на то что ответили только на последний<…>" - это комментарий под видео: https://youtu.be/uPM3qiViSd0 - от пользователя WoT Games.

Comment: «... или даже слитно» тоже примера требует.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая между *то* и *что* ставится не всегда. Вот, например, союз [НЕСМОТРЯ НА ТО(,) ЧТО](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_483) — иногда запятая ставится только перед *несмотря*. Или "расчлененный союз "не то что... но":

> Вопрос № 294751
>   Здравствуйте. Подскажите, надо ли ставить запятую перед "если" в предложении: "Народ если и рассматривает данный вариант, то считает его безумием"? И прошу разъяснить, почему надо или не надо ставить запятую.
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   При однородных членах предложения, кроме одиночных или повторяющихся союзов, могут употребляться двойные (сопоставительные) союзы, которые членятся на две части, располагающиеся каждая при каждом члене предложения: как... так и, не только... но и, не столько... сколько, насколько... настолько, хотя и... но, если не... то, **не то что... но**, не то чтобы... а, не только не... а, скорее... чем и др. Запятая всегда ставится перед второй частью таких союзов. Верно: Народ если и рассматривает данный вариант, то считает его безумием.

Выражение "**то что надо**" может писаться без запятой. [Ответы Грамоты:](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=%D0%A1%E2%80%9A%D0%A0%D1%95%20%D0%A1%E2%80%A1%D0%A1%E2%80%9A%D0%A0%D1%95%20%D0%A0%D0%85%D0%A0%C2%B0%D0%A0%D2%91%D0%A0%D1%95)

> Вопрос № 276158
>   Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, правильно ли поставлена запятая: А денек выдался то, что надо.
>   Заранее спасибо за ответ.
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Запятая не требуется: А денек выдался **то что надо**.
>
> Вопрос № 257690
>   здравствуйте. нужна ли запятая перед "что" : Я рассмотрел ваше предложение - то что надо. 
>   какими членами предложения здесь являются "то" и "что"?
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Запятая не нужна. В значении 'хороший, годный' слова **то что надо** выступают в роли неразложимого по смыслу сочетания и не разделяются запятыми. Ср.: Я рассмотрел ваше предложение – то, что надо было рассмотреть